# Subtraction of sub query counts DB2

Tags: db2

i am trying to take the difference of the counts of 2 sub queries. But i get the following error. I executed the two sub queries separately and it works fine. The error may be because way i try to convert them to a single query. Any ideas?

[image]

```
select
(select count(*) FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER where 
rtrim(ltrim(translate(PNU_POL,' ','1234567890'))) = '') 
- 
(select count(*) FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER )
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try selecting from `DUAL`:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER
     WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(TRANSLATE(PNU_POL, ' ', '1234567890'))) = '') -
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER)
FROM DUAL;
```

Actually, there is a single query workaround you can use involving conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(TRANSLATE(PNU_POL, ' ', '1234567890'))) = ''
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - COUNT(*)
FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER
```

Comment: it says "DUAL" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE = 42704

Comment: What is `PNU_POL` and are you sure that both subqueries run individually?

Comment: I don't know how to fix your problem, but you don't need to subtract two subqueries here, you can just use a single table level query.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 :

```
values  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER where trim(translate(PNU_POL,'          ','1234567890')) = '') 
      - (SELECT COUNT(*) nb FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER)
```

Comment: `VALUES` often makes more sense that a query over a fake file such as SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 or DUAL.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 :

```
SELECT sum(case when trim(translate(PNU_POL,'           ','1234567890')) = '' then 1 else 0 end) - count(*)
FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3 :

```
select  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER where trim(translate(PNU_POL,' ','1234567890')) = '') 
      - (SELECT COUNT(*) nb FROM TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER)
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 4 :

```
select sum(nb) from 
(                                    
  select count(*) nb                                       
  from TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER where trim(translate(PNU_POL,'          ','1234567890')) = ''     
  union all                                                
  select  -count(*) nb                                     
  from TESTEA.AIT_P_NUMBER                                            
) nb
```